# fit text in container and break line if necessary css

Tags: css, whitespace, inline

I''m making a post commments list, but I'm getting trouble with the comment text.

I want the container div to fit with the text, and at the same time being able to trim long words.  like using `white-space: pre-wrap;`

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
max-width:300px;
}

li{
max-width:300px;
border:1px solid red;
}

.comment{
display:inline-block;
background:green;
max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
  <ul>

   <li>
       <div class=name>Name</div>
          <div class=comment>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </div>
     </li>

    <li>
       <div class=name>Name</div>
          <div class=comment>Lorem ipsumsit ametconsectetur adipiscing</div>
     </li>
      
    
    <li>
       <div class=name>Name</div>
          <div class=comment>Lorem ipsum  </div>
     </li>
     
     
        
    <li>
       <div class=name>Name</div>
          <div class=comment>Lorem ipsumametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsecteturametconsectetur  </div>
     </li>

</ul>
```

How do II ahieve this? `display:inline-block` and `white-space: pre-wrap;` or so? This is for mobile, so the text have to shrink and mantain these properties.

Comment: use `word-break: break-all;`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `word-wrap: break-word;`

```
.comment {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    max-width: 300px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```